# How to Connect to Available Bluetooth Printers and Print from Windows 10 Universal App?

Tags: printing, windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

How to Connect to Available Bluetooth Printers from Windows 10 Universal  App??

Requirement is that There are will be list of printers available which are Bluetooth enabled.

How can i connect to that Bluetooth enabled printers and print from my Universal Windows app.?

Answer (score 0):

> How to Connect to Available Bluetooth Printers and Print from Windows 10 Universal App?

For how to print from windows 10 universal app, please reference the official document: [Print from your app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app) and the [official print sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing).

If you want to assign the printer you want to use , please choose the printer in the `PrinterUI`. Please ensure you have added the printer to the printer list. For how to add printers please go to `Settings->Devices->Printers&Scanners` .

If you did not add the printer, the `PrinterUI` also provide an option to `Add a printer` and you can choose to navigate to the setting page.
[image]

For how to add a printer through discovered by Bluetooth please reference the following picture.

[image]

By the way, although more than 1900 printers are supported in uwp, but there are still have printers are not supported, details please reference [Developing Apps That Print in Windows 10](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/build/2015/2-94).